# FPDI parse pdf file from remote url

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

How can i parse pdf(s) from url not a from local folder?

`$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($local_pdf_file);`
This above code working fine, i can get pdf from local folder and can write my text to pdf, but i want to get pdf from url, from remote server. I tried this:

```
$remote_url = 'https://remoteserver.com/file.pdf';
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($remote_url));
```

But this not working, i also used fopen, file_get_contents. i cant get good results, How can i do this ? Thanks for all.

```
// get the page count
            $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($local_pdf_file);
            // iterate through all pages
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
                // import a page
                $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
                // get the size of the imported page
                $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

                // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
                if ($size[0] > $size[1]) {
                    $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size[0], $size[1]));
                } else {
                    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size[0], $size[1]));
                }

                // use the imported page
                $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

                $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
                $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
                $pdf->Write(8, 'Watermark');
            }

            $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: You can get a pdf file from a remote server, but you can't write the pdf file on a remote server. You need to write it on a local server.

Comment: Yes  I Know, i tried get file from remote server, and save it to local temp directory then edit. after upload to remote server again, but i cant

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this:

`use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader;`

use like this:

```
$pdf = new Pdf(); // Fpdf instance

$file = file_get_contents('https://.../custom-filename.pdf');

$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($file));
```

Good luck!